# Using Google OAuth 2.0 for Client-side Authentication not working

Tags: javascript, api, calendar, oauth-2.0

I am using google API for my calendar. It worked perfectly last days but now its showing some errors in my browser console

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.en.JpdoJPJ5hQs.O/m=client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=AQ/rs=AGLTcCMrDhGj8PwnRZ6lDn8FgkiuwDfUVw/t=zcms/cb=gapi.loaded_0
```

I am sure that there are no changes in my code.
What happens to my app? Please help me!

Comment: A `404` means the resource is missing or cannot be found. Check whether the link has been updated.

Comment: It returns nothing. However, this link was created from Google code (library) to authenticate requests. What should I do :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several hours to research, I realize that everything is in `client.js` file. When I build this app, instead of using this code 
`<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=checkAuth"></script>` for get code from Google directly, I downloaded it and saved on local. The problem is that this code will be updated by Google automatically, so we must update it too.

In summary:

Cause: source code was change by Google

Solution: update source code on local or use

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=checkAuth"></script>
```

P.s: sorry for my bad English :D